# Keras Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 4, 3) are incompatible

Tags: python, keras

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
x=[[[13.0, 10.0], [12.0, 28.0], [10.0, 14.0], [6.0, 53.0]], [[12.0, 53.0], [13.0, 53.0], [10.0, 53.0], [3.0, 31.44]], [[15.0, 28.0], [16.0, 28.0], [13.0, 28.0], [6.0, 28.0]]]
y=[0, 1, 2]
x=np.array(x).reshape(-1,4,2)
y=to_categorical(np.array(y),num_classes=3)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu',input_shape=(4,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=20)
```

Get Error:
ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 4, 3) are incompatible

I've tried everything, I want 4 elements with 2 values in each to be fed to the input, and class 0 1 or 2 to the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at the end of your model, when you add your output layer its shape is (None, 3) while the rest of your layers are still (None, 4, 3). All you need to do is add a Flatten() layer and it should work no problem!

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
x=[[[13.0, 10.0], [12.0, 28.0], [10.0, 14.0], [6.0, 53.0]], [[12.0, 53.0], [13.0, 53.0], [10.0, 53.0], [3.0, 31.44]], [[15.0, 28.0], [16.0, 28.0], [13.0, 28.0], [6.0, 28.0]]]
y=[0, 1, 2]
x=np.array(x).reshape(-1,4,2)
y=to_categorical(np.array(y),num_classes=3)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=20)
```